# Laravet Carbon date setTimezone(8) giving +0700

Tags: laravel, timezone, php-carbon

I want to set timezone to GMT+8

```
$data = Carbon::now();
$data->setTimezone(8);
```

but the result given is

```
Carbon @1521099609 {#2145
  date: 2018-03-15 14:40:09.759487 Asia/Krasnoyarsk (+07:00)
}
```

I have no idea why it happen, so I must use timezone name to get exact date I want?

Comment: try `$data->->timezone('America/Los_Angeles');`

Comment: it expects the timezone name as stated by @Sohel0415

Comment: If timezone name is expected, why it can accept timezone number like 0-7, and only I set with timezone 8 will returned me invalid data, if it is 7, then the date is correct just the timezone name is not.

Comment: @YuYenkan look at my answer, it should do your task, just tested

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$data = Carbon::now();
$data->setTimezone('Asia/Krasnoyarsk');
```

Also make sure to set the timezone else it will have  the default value which is set in your `php.ini` file

```
Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First get the [timezone](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_timezone_name_from_abbr.asp) name, then `set`:

```
$data = Carbon::now();
$timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("", 8*3600, false);

if($timezoneName)
     $data->setTimezone($timezoneName);
```